# Rule control to windows form (word style)

Tags: c#, controls, winforms

There are any control who can draw a rule regardless of the screen resolution? e.g. I wanna draw some text box 2 inches left and 3 inches down, and i wanna put the rules to guide the user. 
Or any idea to develop something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking out this project: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ruler.aspx